# How to access equal number of rows in each category in mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to access rows from a table with matching values, In my table, I have 3 columns each column may contain 1 or 0 like below

```
column1      column2      column3
  1            0           0
  0            1           0 
  0            0           1
  1            1           0 
  0            0           1
  0            1           0
  .            .           .
  .            .           .
```

This is what I tried

```
$query = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM tableName LIMIT 10";
        $Res =  $connection->query($query);

        if($Res->rowCount() > 0) {

            while($rows = $Res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                if($rows['column1'] == 1) {

                 //body

                    }

                    if($rows['column2'] == 1) {

                 //body

                    }

                    if($rows['column3'] == 1) {

                 //body

                    }
        }
    }
```

but here I am not getting each column with 10 rows.

Comment: This query returns 10 (arbitrary) rows for each column (provided that at least 10 rows exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given `limit 10` so it will fetch 10 rows only from table without looking if there are `0's` or `1's` in that column ,so to overcome this one way is to remove `limit 10` instead used `count` to keep count of `1's` and only print `10 rows`. Like below  :

```
    $query = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM tableName ";
        $Res =  $connection->query($query);
   //counter for getting rows having 1's
   c=0;
   c1=0;
   c2=0;
        if($Res->rowCount() > 0) {

            while($rows = $Res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                if($rows['column1'] == 1) {
                //checking if counter is < = to 10
                   if(c<=10){
                   //do something
                    c++; 
                   }
                 }

                    if($rows['column2'] == 1) {

                     if(c1<=10){
                   //do something
                    c1++; 
                   }
                }

               if($rows['column3'] == 1) {

                  if(c2<=10){
                   //do something
                    c2++; 
                   }

             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if anyone column has 1 then I need to fetch. Means I need to fetch rows individually.

Comment: sorry i missunderstood your question , now check !